# material-ui TextField not clearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Currently using this version of material-ui: "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.1".
This is the piece of code that is not consistent with the examples provided on the website:

```
<div>
    <TextField id="outlined-search" label="Search field" type="search" variant="outlined" size="small"/>
</div>
```

On my application it looks like this: [no x icon in TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3axdu.png)

On the example code-sandbox it looks like this: [x icon present in TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7CG6.png)

Not quite sure what the problem is, as it seems quite straightforward. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the actual component API, its working perfectly.

Try to update your dependencies since the latest version of material-ui is 4.8.2.
you can update them by using `npm update` or `yarn upgrade`.

If that does not fix the issue there seems to be some style that is not loading in your application causing the clear button to disappear. going to need your code to diagnose further.

Comment: ```import {TextField} from "@material-ui/core";
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SearchByFilter extends Component {

    render() {
        const {handleTagChange} = this.props;
        return (
            <TextField
                id="search"
                name="filter_name"
                label="Filter by Tag"
                variant="outlined"
                type="search"
                onChange={handleTagChange('filter_name')}
                size={"small"}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default SearchByFilter;```

Comment: Sorry that it's not very readable... I tried updating it too and it didn't seem to do anything. I think you are right that something is not being loaded because the line of code is very simple, can't think of what else went wrong

Comment: Are you using SSR rendering ? if so it might me a problem with that I had a lot of issues with styles not loading while using SSR with material UI Components. try using a gatsby plugin to load styles instead of the code that material ui make styles does might solve it.